# Scala: How to define anonymous function with implicit parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I want to define a function with implicit parameter in a way like this:

```
// imports to add scope of A

{
  implicit a: A => {
    // some action
  }
}.apply()

// somewhere in the code           

class A

val a: A = new A
```

But my `Scala` compiler doesn't compile it. It says: `Cannot resolve reference apply with such signature`. However, the parameter is implicit, so I guess compiler should look up in the scope and find an appropriate object.

Is it true? If not, then how can I fix it?

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to achieve, at least to me

Comment: I want to fire a function and force it to use implicit param. I don't want to pass the param to the function explicitly.

Comment: Oh ok I get what you mean, I skipped the 'anonymous' part of the question. You can't then, only methods can have implicit parameters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. Only methods can have implicit parameters.

When you do this:

```
// val f: A => Unit = 
{
   implicit a: A => {
     // some action
   }
}
```

you're actually declaring an anonymous function of type `A => Unit` and you are declaring the argument `a` as implicit *in the function body*

---

You can achieve something close to what you want using the magnet pattern:

```
class A

case class Magnet()
object Magnet {
  implicit def fromUnit(arg1: Unit)(implicit a: A) = Magnet()
}

object Test extends App {

  implicit val a = new A

  {
    args: Magnet => {
      //...
    }
  }.apply()
}
```

You'll get a deprecation warning though because the magnet must have at least one parameter and I used `Unit`, you should call it like `.apply(())` to avoid it

Answer (score 3):

As said by Giovanni: You can't have such a parameter.

However you can use `implicitly` to resolve implicits within your function:

```
case class Foo(text : String)
implicit val foo = Foo("World")

(() => {
  val implFoo : Foo = implicitly[Foo]
  println(s"Hello ${implFoo.text}")
}).apply()
```

*(But to be honest this sounds like it can be written better and you're going into spaghetti code territory with what you're doing.)*